# Win32 RDBSS maximum path and maximum path component length in Windows 11?

Tags: winapi

Windows 11 no longer has the 260 char MAX_PATH limit.

Does the Win32 RDBSS (The Kernel Network Mini-Redirector Driver) API have a path length, or path component length limit?

I turned the Microsoft documentation upside down, and could not find anything.

Comment: *Windows 11 no longer has the 260 char MAX_PATH limit.* even xp have not it. this related only to some types of win32 path during conversion to ntpath. ntpath always have limit related to `UNICODE_STRING` capasity - 32k symbols. path component length - usually `0xFF` (255) symbols

Comment: Here is some official doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry